# Test JSON API service

Tags: php, json, json-api

I recently started working on PHP/JSON and what are the best free online APIs for testing/requesting dummy data?

I'm currently using HTTPFUL lib from http://phphttpclient.com/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a browser extension, i.e. [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) for Chrome or [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/restclient/) for Firefox.

**UPDATE**

I'm generally using [BreweryDB](http://www.brewerydb.com/developers) to test API clients. This is a classic REST API for which you just need a simple key to access data.

Comment: Awesome. But I would like to know some URLs that I can use for requesting dummy data.